# 1D FFT transform of 2D array in CUDA

Tags: c#, cuda

I want to do 1-D FFT of a 2-D array (say along columns only). I am using vs2010/C# with managedcuda.

I am having some problems:

1. How to I make a 2-D CudaDeviceVariable? I tried:

   ```
           int n1 = 10;
           int n2 = 2;
           int batch = 1;
           //SizeT test;

           CudaDeviceVariable<double>[,] datad;
           datad = new CudaDeviceVariable<double>[n1, n2];
   ```

But `datad` is not a `CudaDeviceVariable`. Its a normal 2-D array now. So I can't allocate memory in device. Like:

```
    double[,] data11 = new double[,] {{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 },{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }};

    datad.CopyToDevice(data11);//Error??
```

It is an error because `CopyToDevice` is not a method for `System.Array`. If I make `datad` a `n1*n2` `CudaDeviceVariable`, error is still there because `CopyToDevice` takes `double[]` as input argument, not `[,].` Above method works for 1-D arrays.

2.is it possible to do 1-D FFT of a large 1-D array. For example, I make 1-D array from `data11`. And then perform FFT in parts of 10 elements? `CudaFFTPlanMany` has some options but I am not 100% clear how to use them or how can they be useful to me.

Please ask more details if I am not clear. Thanks a lot.

EDIT: I got some more details, question still remains, but I made 1-D array of `data11`, and then performed batched fft, in 2 batches of size 10. It gave me results what I wanted. Syntax is:

```
            CudaFFTPlanMany planm;
            planm = new CudaFFTPlanMany(1, n, 1,cufftType.D2Z);
```

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when designing managedCuda I decided against multi-dimensional array support as I couldn’t find any guaranty that the CLR is not allowed to introduce some line pitch. Also multi-dimensional arrays are treated differently when it comes to interop with p/invoke.

So the only supported arrays are simple 1D arrays, similar to arrays in C/C++. A 2D array is therefore only a large 1D array with size `width * height`, and an index is computed like `y * width + x`.

On device side you can use `CudaPitchedDeviceVariable<double>` which introduces some additional bytes to each line in order to begin every array line on a properly aligned memory address -> see also CUDA programming guide, e.g. page 73. On host side, those arrays are still represented as a simple 1D array without any additional pitch.

Regarding your second question on cufft: yes, `CudaFFTPlanMany` with batch is the way to go, managedCuda implements the interface exactly like the original cufft API, for more details see chapter 2 in CUFFT Users guide. For the given example your plan would look like:

```
int[] n = new int[] { 10 };
plan = new CudaFFTPlanMany(1, n, 2, cufftType.D2Z);
```

A special hint for 2D arrays: arrays containing dimension info like `inembed` or `n` are kind of “inverse”: `[height, width]` instead of `[width, height]`...

Comment: thanks a lot. I was just confused about 2-D array. And by the way, it will greatly help if there are a few documented examples. It took me a while to figure things out, given I am not a hardcore CUDA/C programmer. There are examples, but I had to dig in the code to see the implementations. Thanks again. Great work.

Comment: I know, managedCuda misses some simple walk-through examples. But to create them I would need much more time than currently available... Maybe in future ;-)